# Return the element just before the occurrence of another element in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I want to write a code in Haskell, to return an element just before the occurrence of another element in a list. For ex:

eBefore 3 [1,2,3,4,5] should return 2

I am quiet new to haskell. The code that i've written up till now is :

```
eBefore :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe a
eBefore n [] = Nothing
eBefore n (x:xs) = if x == n then Just x else eBefore n xs
```

I would be highly obliged if some one could help me understand the approach or help me out with the problem. Thank you!

Comment: In your example, do you mean it should return `2`?

Comment: Writing your own implementation is a great way to learn.  After that it is also useful to look for, and understand instead of simply accept, alternative implementations.  In this case I encourage you to look at @Andrey's answer and consider  `eBefore n xs = lookup n (zip (drop 1 xs) xs)`

Comment: @RowanBlush yes it should return 2. I am sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match more elaborated patterns:

```
eBefore n [] = Nothing
eBefore n [_] = Nothing
eBefore n (x1:xs@(x2:_))
    | x2 == n   = Just x1
    | otherwise = eBefore n xs
```

Here we return `Nothing` for lists containing zero or one elements because they contain no member with another one preceding them. `(x1:xs@(x2:_))` is a pattern that matches a `x1:xs`, where `xs` in turn matches `x2:_`, that is, a list with at least two elements, the first element is bound to `x1`, the second to `x2`, the residue is unimportant (matched by `_`).

We also might write thus:

```
eBefore n [] = Nothing
eBefore n [_] = Nothing
eBefore n (x1:x2:xs)
    | x2 == n   = Just x1
    | otherwise = eBefore n (x2:xs)
```

However, this variant might be worse in terms of performance. `(x1:x2:xs)` is equivalent to `(x1:(x2:xs))`, and we see that `(x2:xs)` repeated again as an argument to recursive call. But the compiler may fail to recognize the identity of the two expressions and create a new node. That's a waste. By using the `@`-notation in the former variant, we give that `(x2:_)` from the pattern a name, `xs`, and pass it to the recursive call as a ready whole.

The difficult moment here is what we should return in case `n` is equal to the head of the list, e. g. `eBefore 3 [3,4,5,6,3]`. The definition above will skip the first occurrence of 3 and return 6.

Comment: You need `| x2 == n   = Just x1`

Comment: @chi I bet you have enough reputation to make that edit yourself. ;-)

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, I actually wondered whether that was appropriate -- this was probably a simple thing to do, but in general I might be wrong, and I don't like to introduce errors in others' answers, so I am bit conservative in editing.

Comment: @chi, Daniel, thank you for correcting my negligence.